# $_POST is empty in push notification response (PHP)

Tags: php, push-notification

Can anybody tell me how to get the response data from a push notification response. I am currently only able to get data from headers, but $_POST is an empty array. Can anybody push me in the right direction? (I get notifications from google and outlook.)

My notifications file contains code as below:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
file_put_contents('response-data.txt', serialize($_POST));
```

Comment: What format are those notifications send in - JSON? If so: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see that my question resembles the one you link to. But as i can see, he didn't get his problem resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something alike:

```
file_put_contents('response-data.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using file_get_contents('php://input') return empty as well.

Comment: @NIKO_B would assume, there is no post ...what do the httpd logs say? are you certain that this postback-receiver script can be accessed without having to login?

Comment: @NIKO_B this depends on the server; ordinary it's something alike `/var/log/httpd/access_log` or `/var/log/httpd/error_log` - on shared hostings, one may find them in the hosting console.

Comment: Thanks. I found them. The logs don't report any errors. Only 200. @martin-zeitler